# Apple Push Notifications not working from java webservice deployed in Linux

Tags: ios, linux, web-services, apple-push-notifications, javapns

1. Tested  java build with ios production certificate from local windows machines. It was working fine and the push notifications were sent successfully to iphone and ipad.Push notifications are done using javapns.
2. Deployed the same build in Linux machine, but the push notifications are not working now.
3. Granted full  permission for p12 file in linux server.

should we add/grant anything in the linux server for sending push notification from Linux.
Please help to sort out this issue.

Comment: Pls check this: (From Apple documentation): To send notifications, you will need to allow inbound and outbound TCP packets over port 2195. Devices and computers connecting to the push service over Wi-Fi will need to allow inbound and outbound TCP packets over port 5223.
For more info: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG41

Answer (score 0):

check your java version 
JavaPNS javapns-jdk16 Java1.6 compatible